# Only one bucket for object store on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab allow to store [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_artifacts.html), [git lfs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/lfs/lfs_administration.html), [uploads](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/uploads.html), [packages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages.html), [external diffs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/merge_request_diffs.html) and [backups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html) directly on a S3's Bucket but according to documentation is one bucket for artifacts, another for git lfs, other for uploads, etc, etc...

Is possible to use only one bucket for all and just organized with directories?

Comment: S3 buckets don't have directories. It's object storage, not a filesystem.

Comment: S3 looks like it has directories to the users.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html